# Redirecionamento 301 protocolo https para http

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento

Gostaria de fazer um redirecionamento 301 (por meio do .htaccess) apenas em 1 link que eu tenho https para http sem alterar qualquer outro link do servidor ou protocolo.

Link https:
https://meudominio.com/blog/tag/dengue-mata/

Redirecionar Para:
http://meudominio.com/blog/tag/dengue-mata/

OBS: Repare que o link é o mesmo só muda o protocolo https para http;

Obrigado!

Comment: Tentei todas as formas abaixo e não funcionou... Acho que existe uma outra forma de funcionar... Como eu faço para todos meus links que tiver "https://" forem redirecionados para o mesmo link sem o www ? por ex: https: // www. meudominio.com/teste ser redirecionado para https:// meudominio.com/teste

Comment: Se nao funcionou da forma abaixo, alguma outra coisa está errada na sua configuração. Inclusive eu testei todas pra ver quais davam loop e quais não. Tem certeza que seu .htaccess está sendo lido e que está com as permissões necessárias? o mod rewrite está habilitado?

Answer (score 4):

Para os casos em que tudo o que é HTTPS deve ser direccionado para HTTP:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Zull, Obrigado mas ainda não funcionou cara, ele continua indo para o HTTPS (Eu ja mudei o .htaccess da raiz e tbn do /blog, mas não funcionou).

Comment: Viste a resposta do @Bacco ?

Comment: vi sim! Mas como esta escrito la em cima.. ela vai entrar em loop infinito.. pois o link das 2 são iguais.. o que muda é só o https. Tem como vc me add no face para eu explicar melhor? Muito obrigado! https://www.facebook.com/israelvitorino

Answer (score 4):

Baseado na resposta do @Zuul, segue a versão para seu caso específico,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule blog/tag/dengue-mata/ http://meudominio.com/blog/tag/dengue-mata/ [R=301,L]
```

Se pretende usar parâmetros ou algum dado extra depois da barra, pode fazer assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule blog/tag/dengue-mata(.*) http://meudominio.com/blog/tag/dengue-mata$1  [R=301,L]
```

Notar que omiti a barra final, para contemplar URLs sem a barra também. Ajuste conforme a necessidade.

> Importante: se seu domínio não estiver com o certificado correto, ao acessar por `https://`, a mensagem de erro aparecerá antes do redirect de qualquer forma. Isto é da natureza do protocolo, que primeiro faz a conexão segura, para depois solicitar o caminho.

### Cuidado com redirect puro:

O redirect é excelente, mas quando você só troca o protocolo, e o caminho é o mesmo, pode entrar em loop infinito, como neste caso:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/tag/dengue-mata/ http://meudominio.com/blog/tag/dengue-mata/
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso

```
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /blog/tag/dengue-mata/ http://meudominio.com/blog/tag/dengue-mata/
```

Comment: Você criou um loop infinito.

Comment: Leandro, mas e o https ? dessa forma que vc pos vai entrar em loop infinito

Answer (score -2):

```
         var url      = window.location.href;     // Retorna a url completa

        console.log(url);

        var array = url.split(":");  // separa antes e após os :

        console.log(array[0]);

        if(array[0] == "http"){  // faz a comparação

            var trocado = url.replace("http", "https");  // faz a troca

            console.log(trocado);

            window.location.href = trocado;  // redireciona
        }
```