# Redirecionamento Permantente (301) para endereços sem WWW com htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento

Como eu faço para que todos os endereços que tiver "https://" sejam redirecionados para o mesmo endereço porém sem o **www***?

Ex: https://www.meudominio.com/teste redireciona para https://meudominio.com/teste

Obs. APENAS endereços HTTPS, com certificado de segurança!

Comment: Amigo, isso voce configura DNS de onde está hospedado. Tem que atribuir o CNAME.

Comment: Olha esse link aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022324/how-to-setup-dns-for-an-apex-domain-no-www-pointing-to-a-heroku-app

Comment: Oi Israel. Os princípios disso estão respondidos na [sua pergunta anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22025/redirecionamento-301-protocolo-https-para-http). Você poderia esclarecer o que você não entendeu ali?

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu li todos e testei todos porem ele nao SAI DO https e manda pro http por nada! essa resposta abaixo do "abfurlan" parece ser a mais indicada pois ela ve se é o protocolo httpS e se for.. manda pro link sem o S.. porem nao vai nem a pau! (Ja usamos varias regras esta tudo ativado) o prob é só nessa regra mesmo.. não sei pq nao funciona

Comment: Mas a resposta dada aqui é EXATAMENTE a mesma que o @Zuul disse na [sua pergunta anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22025/), e a [minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22035/70) já cobre o caso de mandar pro endereço que você quiser, com ou sem WWW.

Comment: A pergunta é a mesma. Se ela não estava clara antes, então deveria editar a anterior e não criar uma nova.

Comment: Apesar de não ser uma "duplicata literal", o objetivo da pergunta é o mesmo, portanto estou votando como duplicata. Lembre-se que isto não é uma crítica, tampouco "punição", mas mera maneira de organizar o site. Sinta-se à vontade para editar a outra pergunta, e acrescentar os detalhes necessários ao final (de preferência apenas acrescentando o que precisa, sem descaracterizar a pergunta, visto que já há várias respostas que se basearam na solicitação original).

Comment: @Israel Talvez outra regra esteja impedindo essa de entrar. Não quer incluir seu htaccess completo na pergunta, e reformulá-la para que faça sentido após a edição? Nesse caso eu acho que ela pode ser reaberta.