# Redirecionamento sem www

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirecionamento-de-url, w3c-validador

Como procedo na seguinte situação:

Minha *URLs* antigas eram do *blogger*, e possuíam o *WWW.*
Passei para o *Wordpress* e removi o *WWW.*
Hoje recebi mensagem do google *WEBMASTER*:

> Aumento de páginas "404"

Isso acontece pois redirecionei todas as *URLs* que tinham *www* para sem, alteram todos os parâmetros,mas eu não sei porquê o Google indexou algumas *urls* antigas sem o *WWW.*.

Existe uma maneira mais simples para corrigir isso?, pois se não terei que redirecionar mais *200 URLs*.

```
http://www.meusite.com/3/1/site.html
http://meusite.com/site/
```

Mas:

```
http://meusite.com/3/1/site.html
Erro 404
```

Não existe uma maneira deu verificar a existência do *.html* no final e caso tenha adiciono o *www* na frente do domínio?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22173/redirecionamento-permantente-301-para-endereços-sem-www-com-htaccess?rq=1

Comment: @Diego Realizei através de Plugin. Onde tinha as URLs direcionadas com www. Daí colocoquei no notepad++ e removi o "WWW." e importei para o plugin que já está redirecionando. ATT